Rollup grouping sets
I have a table and a view that utilize the Oracle ROLLUP function.
Please refer to the details here: dbfiddle.
I wonder if it would be possible to only calculate sums for certain columns using ROLLUP. For instance:



Year
Customer

Jan
Feb
...
Dec




2023
Customer1
Article1
1
1
...
1


2023
Customer1
Article2
1
1
...
1


2023
Customer1
Sum
2
2
...
2


2023
Customer1
Article3
1
1
...
1


2023
Customer1
Article4
1
1
...
1



I would like to have a sum row after Article1 and Article2, but not after Article3 and Article4.
In my example in fiddle, I wish to determine if it is possible to hide the 'Sum' row below the line where 'Bücher- Warensendungen' occurs.

Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with the CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements for your sample data. At the moment your question includes an output with no data to be able to replicate it and the fiddle contains a different set of data (with only a rough guide as to what the expected output is). You should use a single set of data and the data should be included in the question so that the question is self-contained and the expected output matches the data (but you can also include a link to the fiddle if you want).

FYI The link to example in fiddle has been there from the begining.

Yes, but my point was that the question does not contain a [MRE] and does not match the fiddle. If you are going to provide a fiddle then it should match the question (and the CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements should also be included in the question so that the question is self-contained if the link to the fiddle ever dies).

Since mbr_prodgr_id and mbr_prodgr appear to have a one-to-one correlation, you do not appear to need to ROLLUP both of them; just ROLLUP the primary key (presumably mbr_prodgr_id) and find the other with aggregation.
Then you can use:
SELECT year,       
       gp_gr_id,
       mbr_gr_id,
       gp_id,
       bezirk_id,
       mbr_prodgr_id,
       CASE
       WHEN GROUPING_ID(mbr_prodgr_id) = 1
       THEN 'Sum'
       ELSE MAX(mbr_prodgr)
       END AS mbr_prodgr,
       COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN month = 4 THEN summe END), 0) AS apr,
       COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN month = 5 THEN summe END), 0) AS mai,
       COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN month = 6 THEN summe END), 0) AS juni,
       sum(summe) summe_jahr 
FROM   t 
WHERE  deleted =0 
AND    mbr_prodgr_id IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY 
       year,
       gp_gr_id,
       mbr_gr_id,
       gp_id,
       bezirk_id,
       ROLLUP(mbr_prodgr_id)
HAVING (GROUPING_ID(mbr_prodgr_id), MAX(mbr_prodgr_id)) NOT IN ((1, 12))
ORDER BY
       year,
       gp_gr_id,
       mbr_gr_id,
       gp_id,
       bezirk_id,
       mbr_prodgr_id

or maybe (depending on if you want to filter using mbr_prodgr_id or mbr_gr_id):
SELECT year,       
       gp_gr_id,
       mbr_gr_id,
       gp_id,
       bezirk_id,
       mbr_prodgr_id,
       CASE
       WHEN GROUPING_ID(mbr_prodgr_id) = 1
       THEN 'Sum'
       ELSE MAX(mbr_prodgr)
       END AS mbr_prodgr,
       COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN month = 4 THEN summe END), 0) AS apr,
       COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN month = 5 THEN summe END), 0) AS mai,
       COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN month = 6 THEN summe END), 0) AS juni,
       sum(summe) summe_jahr 
FROM   t 
WHERE  deleted =0 
AND    mbr_prodgr_id IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY 
       year,
       gp_gr_id,
       mbr_gr_id,
       gp_id,
       bezirk_id,
       ROLLUP(mbr_prodgr_id)
HAVING (GROUPING_ID(mbr_prodgr_id), mbr_gr_id) NOT IN ((1, 3))
ORDER BY
       year,
       gp_gr_id,
       mbr_gr_id,
       gp_id,
       bezirk_id,
       mbr_prodgr_id

Which, for the sample data (taken from the fiddle):
CREATE TABLE T (
  GP_ID          INTEGER,
  MBR_GR_ID      INTEGER,
  BEZIRK_ID      INTEGER,
  GEBIET_ID      INTEGER,
  MBR_ID         INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY ( START WITH 92541 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 MINVALUE 1 NOCYCLE CACHE 20 NOORDER NOKEEP NOSCALE) NOT NULL,
  MONTH          INTEGER,
  YEAR           INTEGER,
  SUMME          INTEGER,
  GP_GR_ID       INTEGER,
  DELETED        INTEGER,
  IS_SUM         INTEGER,
  MBR_PRODGR     VARCHAR2(32 BYTE),
  MBR_PRODGR_ID  NUMBER
);

insert into t (
  MBR_GR_ID, MBR_ID, MONTH, YEAR,
  SUMME, GP_GR_ID, DELETED, MBR_PRODGR, MBR_PRODGR_ID
)
SELECT 1, 60884, 5, 2023, 3, 5, 0, 'Standardbrief', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 60885, 5, 2023, 1, 5, 0, 'Standardbrief', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 60886, 5, 2023, 1, 5, 0, 'Standardbrief', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 60887, 5, 2023, 1, 5, 0, 'Standardbrief', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 60888, 5, 2023, 2, 5, 0, 'Kompaktbrief',  3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 60889, 5, 2023, 2, 5, 0, 'Maxibrief',     5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 60890, 5, 2023, 2, 5, 0, 'Maxibrief',     5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 60891, 5, 2023, 2, 5, 0, 'Maxibrief',     5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 60892, 5, 2023, 1, 5, 0, 'Standardbrief', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 60893, 5, 2023, 1, 5, 0, 'Großbrief',     4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 60894, 5, 2023, 1, 5, 0, 'Standardbrief', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 60895, 5, 2023, 2, 5, 0, 'Maxibrief',     5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 60896, 5, 2023, 2, 5, 0, 'Info Standard', 7 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 60897, 5, 2023, 2, 5, 0, 'Info Standard', 7 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 60898, 5, 2023, 2, 5, 0, 'Info Standard', 7 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 60899, 5, 2023, 2, 5, 0, 'Info Standard', 7 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 60900, 5, 2023, 2, 5, 0, 'Info Standard', 7 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 60901, 5, 2023, 2, 5, 0, 'Info Groß',     9 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 60902, 5, 2023, 1, 5, 0, 'Standardbrief', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 60903, 5, 2023, 1, 5, 0, 'Standardbrief', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 60904, 5, 2023, 1, 5, 0, 'Großbrief',     4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 60905, 5, 2023, 2, 5, 0, 'Maxibrief',     5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 60906, 5, 2023, 2, 5, 0, 'Standardbrief', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 60907, 5, 2023, 1, 5, 0, 'Großbrief',     4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 60908, 5, 2023, 1, 5, 0, 'Standardbrief', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 60909, 5, 2023, 2, 5, 0, 'Maxibrief',     5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 60910, 5, 2023, 1, 5, 0, 'Bücher- Warensendungen', 12 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 60911, 5, 2023, 1, 5, 0, 'Großbrief',     4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 60912, 5, 2023, 2, 5, 0, 'Standardbrief', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 60913, 5, 2023, 1, 5, 0, 'Großbrief',     4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 60914, 5, 2023, 1, 5, 0, 'Großbrief',     4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 60915, 5, 2023, 1, 5, 0, 'Standardbrief', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 60916, 5, 2023, 1, 5, 0, 'Standardbrief', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 60917, 5, 2023, 1, 5, 0, 'Großbrief',     4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 60918, 5, 2023, 2, 5, 0, 'Kompaktbrief',  3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 60919, 5, 2023, 2, 5, 0, 'Maxibrief',     5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 60920, 5, 2023, 2, 5, 0, 'Standardbrief', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 60921, 5, 2023, 2, 5, 0, 'Maxibrief',     5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 60922, 5, 2023, 2, 5, 0, 'Kompaktbrief',  3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 60923, 5, 2023, 1, 5, 0, 'Bücher- Warensendungen', 12 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 60924, 5, 2023, 1, 5, 0, 'Standardbrief', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 60925, 5, 2023, 1, 5, 0, 'Bücher- Warensendungen', 12 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 60926, 5, 2023, 1, 5, 0, 'Standardbrief', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 60927, 5, 2023, 2, 5, 0, 'Kompaktbrief',  3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 60928, 5, 2023, 1, 5, 0, 'Großbrief',     4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 60929, 5, 2023, 1, 5, 0, 'Standardbrief', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 60930, 5, 2023, 1, 5, 0, 'Standardbrief', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 60931, 5, 2023, 1, 5, 0, 'Standardbrief', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 60932, 5, 2023, 1, 5, 0, 'Großbrief',     4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 60933, 5, 2023, 4, 5, 0, 'Maxibrief',     5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 60934, 5, 2023, 2, 5, 0, 'Kompaktbrief',  3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 60935, 5, 2023, 1, 5, 0, 'Großbrief',     4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 60936, 5, 2023, 1, 5, 0, 'Bücher- Warensendungen', 12 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 60937, 5, 2023, 1, 5, 0, 'Standardbrief', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 60938, 5, 2023, 6, 5, 0, 'Maxibrief',     5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 60939, 5, 2023, 2, 5, 0, 'Standardbrief', 2 FROM DUAL;

Both outputs:



YEAR
GP_GR_ID
MBR_GR_ID
GP_ID
BEZIRK_ID
MBR_PRODGR_ID
MBR_PRODGR
APR
MAI
JUNI
SUMME_JAHR




2023
5
1
null
null
2
Standardbrief
0
27
0
27


2023
5
1
null
null
3
Kompaktbrief
0
10
0
10


2023
5
1
null
null
4
Großbrief
0
10
0
10


2023
5
1
null
null
5
Maxibrief
0
26
0
26


2023
5
1
null
null
null
Sum
0
73
0
73


2023
5
2
null
null
7
Info Standard
0
10
0
10


2023
5
2
null
null
9
Info Groß
0
2
0
2


2023
5
2
null
null
null
Sum
0
12
0
12


2023
5
3
null
null
12
Bücher- Warensendungen
0
4
0
4



fiddle
